# What is wrong with this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I am applying for a scholarship and this sentence doesn't sound right to me...

> I, therefore, urge the Foundation to provide me with their generous
>   support that would not only make my education possible but would also
>   ensure a desirable future for me.

Towards the end, I want to say that the scholarship will allow me to have a future that I wish to have and so I used the phrase "desirable future." But somehow "make my education possible" doesn't seem parallel with " ensure a desirable future for me." How do I make these phrases chime?

Comment: They chime perfectly fine. They are completely parallel. Whether it’s actually true is another matter. I would say it’s the education, not the loan, that will help you obtain the future you want—and neither loan nor education can **ensure** it. It wouldn’t be the future if it could be ensured.

Comment: 'Therefore I ...' sounds far more natural. I'd prefer a second sentence starting 'This would ...'. '...ensure a desirable future for me' sounds rather ego-centric. However, this is off-topic as writing advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks writing advice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't want it sound ego-centric. What would you suggest?

Comment: That would make my education possible and enable me to embark upon a successful career, one in which I can in turn make contributions back into society.

Comment: *back into society* Better than frontally, I suppose.

Comment: IMHO, it also suffers from sounding too flowery and affectedly old-fashioned. The phrase "desirable future" sounds very stilted, and the fact that you begin the sentence with "I" *and* end the sentence with "me" bookends it quite badly. I think that may be why it comes off as egocentric; [primacy and recency effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_position_effect).

Comment: Grammatically, the sentence could be improved by changing "support that" to "support, which". The phrases with the verbs _make_ and _ensure_ seem perfectly parallel and compatible. But as a sales pitch (which this is: you are asking the foundation to purchase your education), the sentence seems all wrong. You should show why the investment in you furthers _the foundation's_ goals. The reason may be that you have greater need than other applicants (who may be educated without the funding) or that your education will benefit society more, depending on the underlying purpose of the scholarship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the sentence is grammatically correct and as formal as needed, the tone of the sentence is too forceful, not diplomatic. When you say you "urge the Foundation to provide me with their generous support," you are asking a big favor. The words *urge, provide*, and *generous* do not go together politely.

I say one has to go, as follows:

You could say you would appreciate their generous support:

- **appreciate** it if the Foundation would provide me with their generous support

You could encourage those generous people to consider your request:

- urge the Foundation to **consider providing** me with their generous support

You could urge those people to be as generous as possible:

- urge the Foundation to provide me with support **as generous as allowed**

On a more minor point, the parallel structure of "support that *would not only* make ... but *would also* ensure" should leave out the second *would*. The structure is *would not only A but also B*, and so needs no second *would*. The first *would* applies to both verb phrases.

Answer (score 0):

Ergo, I urge the Foundation to provide their generous support. This would not only enable my education, but also ensure a desirable future for me.